# Probability for events that can not be happened together

Tags: probability

In a probability experiment, A, B and C are independent events. The probability that A will occur is r,  the probability that B will occur is s, and  the probability that C will occur is  t  whereas the  r, s , and t are grater than zero.
 Now I want to  find a probability that, either A, B or C can occur but they can not occur  together (like AAB or AAC is not allowed but AAA or BBB is allowed.)

In this case I used exclusion-inclusion formula to calculate the probability  in this way:

$$P = P(A \cup B \cup C) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) -P(A\cap B) -P(A\cap  B\cap C)  $$

Is it a correct way?

Comment: It almost  sounds as if you are asking for the probability that exactly  one of  A, B, C occurs, but then the AAB not allowed but AAA allowed makes me wonder what the problem is about,

Comment: Yes only one of A, B or C will  occur.

Comment: I don't think  the formula in the OP is right, but it is late and my blood caffeine level is low. The probability of exactly one is $r(1-s)(1-t)+s(1-r)(1-t)+t(1-r)(1-s)$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas,  you are right and I got you that  how you have done it but how to do it using set formula.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your set formula. Draw a Venn diagram to understand that it should be

$P = P(A \cup B \cup C) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) -P(A\cap B) +2*P(A\cap  B\cap C)$

Comment: There will 2 in front of $P(A\cap  B\cap C)$

Comment: Quite - right !!